# Qt Quick scene graph in a thread flickering during the resize

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, scenegraph

I am playing with QML scene graph in a [thread example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinthread-example.html). When you resize the window on mac, you'll experience bad flicker. Is there any way to fix it / work around it? Is that a bug in the example, or in Qt Quick?

Comment: It's probably a Qt bug. Check the bug database, if a bug doesn't exist make sure that you include a link to the exact example you're using. Also add this link to this question.

Comment: I've just run this example on my Mac (OS X 10.10.3 and Qt 5.5) and it works perfectly.

Comment: did you try drag the frame to resize the window

Comment: I've experienced this problem in general before, but I was interacting directly with the window system for render context management. I had to redraw the scene while resizing. I imagine Qt's supposed to be smart enough to do something like this though.